# How to create custom Automator tasks for distribution -- OS X 10.10

Tags: macos, automator

### Problem

I would like to make custom tasks for Automator to send to friends who are learning or even just to make new Automator apps easer to write without having to repeat the same tasks over and over.
For example:
run shell command (uptime) -> speak text -> copy to clipboard

Would it be at all possible to make a task called Uptime and use one task instead of three?

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Using your example, "*For example: run shell command (uptime) -> speak text -> copy to clipboard*" and to answer your question, "*Would it be at all possible to make a task called Uptime and use one task instead of three?*", yes... Simply add one Run Shell Script *Action*  to your Automator *Workflow* and add the following code:

```
uptime | pbcopy
pbpaste | say
```

[image]

This *pipes* the output of `uptime` to the *clipboard* and then *pipes* the content of the *clipboard* to the `say` command.  The output of the `uptime` command is still on the *clipboard* to paste elsewhere, either by additional commands and or using the keyboard and or other normal methods of pasting from the *clipboard*.

**Note:** I'm assuming that when you say "*use one task instead of three*", you're actually referring to an Automator Action, e.g. Run Shell Script, not the number of commands written into that on Action.